# Forward emails to multiple destinations using SQL virtual aliases postfix

Tags: postfix, sql

I'm setting up an email system at the moment, and I need emails to one address to go to about 5 other addresses. I want to do this with postfix virtual aliases (SQL not a file), but I can't seem to get it to go to multiple targets.

Any help appreciated

Comment: there are at least 10 tutorials online which exactly do this.. you might want to search for them. without additional information like on which OS/distribution etc this is nearly impossible to debug without wasting a lot of time.
Additionally you need to show us the logs, the config, and what exactly you have done.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are following a howto similar to https://workaround.org/ispmail/jessie

All you need to do is in your virtual_aliases table is have the same "original to" address listed multiple times, with different "forward to" addresses.